# extern const in embedded C programming

Tags: constants, extern

I want to use array in multiple .c files.(ex. a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
So I declared the array extern const.
Is extern const array located in Flash? Is it in RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extern const will be loaded from the data section of the compiled binary, which is stored on hard disk, into memory. During execution, it is always in memory. To be precisely, it will be in the data section of the process.